# 2 Images, same object: tone difference and alignment

Tags: textures, image, color, post-processing

I would like to know a software which helps in post-production to calculate the general color/tone difference of 2 images. The images contain the same object, but arn't shot from the same position. One image might be sunny, the other cloudy, so one is more orange/yellow, the other more grey/blue, but the same object.

How would you align the tone of the image?

Background info: i shoot a couple of hundreds of images to produce textures for my models, the objects are outside, so weather conditions can change at any time, shooting must continue. I do photogrammetry, so I use the images to project them on the geometry and bake them in a UV Map. So in general I have a chunk of images made in sunny condition and another in cloudy. I would like to apply a tone to all cloudy images, having similar tone like in the sunny images.

It's not about HDR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where software such as GIMP or Photoshop come into play. There's going to be plenty of tutorials covering subjects such as image correction, replacing background objects, etc...

If I were doing this in Photoshop for example, it would be trivial to load both images into separate layers and then correct them to match.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I found Lightroom to be usefull to automatically apply white-balancing on many files. For next shooting I will use a color-palette to adjust illumination conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In some photogrammetry softwares, you can select which photos should be used for texturing. So split your session into 2:

1) Take photos for texturing from a perfect angle (=parallel to the object)

2) Take photos just for 3D reconstruction

During 1), the lighting has to be the same, so work quickly. 
During 2), lighting doesn't matter much, you can take time for that.